# Modeling to use same FK name of a unchanged database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

I am using EF6 but...
I can not change the database.
So, if I'm not wrong, I need to create a model that suits the database.

I have to models in relationship one to many:

```
[Table("ReceCli")]
    public class ReceCli
    {
        [Key]
        public int Indice { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(12)]
        [Display(Name = "Nº Documento")]
        public string NDOC { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Banco do boleto")]
        [Column("CodBancoBoleto")]
        public int CodBancoBoleto { get; set; }
        public Banco Banco { get; set; }

    }
```

and

```
[Table("Bancos")]
    public class Banco
    {
        [Key]
        public int CodBanco { get; set; }

        [Column("Banco")]
        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Banco")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
```

In the database this relations are expressing like:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReceCli]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ReceCli_CodBancoBoleto] FOREIGN KEY([CodBancoBoleto])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Bancos] ([CodBanco])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ReceCli] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ReceCli_CodBancoBoleto]
```

When executing return an error:

**Invalid column name 'Banco_CodBanco'.**

I can not change the database.

How can I change the model to EF use ReceCli_CodBancoBoleto name of column instead of Banco_CodBanco ?

Comment: Use the Column attribute like you did for `Nome`?

Comment: Ty Erik I think about this. I tried use the Column with the name ReceCli_CobBancoBoleto (FK name in database) but I received this error:Invalid column name 'ReceCli_CodBancoBoleto'. And again:
Invalid column name 'Banco_CodBanco'. And I tried to use [ForeignKey("CodBancoBoleto")] but dont work too.

Comment: You don't use the constraint name, you use the references part.

Comment: And what do you mean when "executing" returns an error?  Are you trying to generate the DB from your EF?  Are you trying to run a query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do model an existing db by hand but you can also tell EF to [generate the model from an existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620).

As for your example, a couple of things:

1. The relationship you have modeled is **not one to many** but one to one.

   Public Banco Banco {get; set;}

Change To:

```
Public ICollection<Banco> Bancos {get;set;}
```

There are several ways you can model relationships with EF.  Here's a sample of [Modeling 1 to many relationships in EF.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

2. The Column attribute is used to match to names in the DB.  Make sure your EF CF properties that don't match the database have a Column Attribute. For Your RecCli it should look something like:

   ```
   [Column("CodBanco")]
   public int CodBancoBoleto { get; set; }
   ```

or

```
 public int CodBanco { get; set; }
```

However, you are mapping a 1 to many relationship so having the CodBancoBoleto is not needed.  Just use the navigation property of `Public ICollection<Banco> Bancos {get;set;}`.  This should suffice except you ***might*** have to put a ForeignKey attribute for it telling it to use CodBanco as the key for the navigation.

```
[ForeignKey("CodBanco")] 
Public ICollection<Banco> Bancos {get;set;}
```

You might have to do this for all your keys as the default code first convention for keys end with Id.  I say might as your Banco Class's key is named properly CodBanco and marked with the Key.  So you might be fine.

A final note is that you appear to be trying to use the constraints name for the mapping.  You don't use the constraint name, rather the actual column names, aka the references part of the constraint.

Comment: TY klabranche. Mine is really a one-to-one relationship. After your suggestion I used EF to generate the models from the database. But when the controller run var receClis = db.ReceClis.Include(r => r.Cliente). I continue got the error: Invalid column name 'Banco_CodBanco'. As I said, can not execute migrations and database is unchangeable.

Comment: Have you tried adding the foreignkey attribute above the int CodBancoBoleto in ReceCli?

Comment: I tried all possibilities with Column and Foreign Key. And now some strange thing happen. I decided to drop the relationship completely from the model, I cut the include in the data load in the controller and even so when I run the controller code it continues to return that the Banco_CodBanco column is invalid.

Comment: Well, this is unfortunately not something I can troubleshoot further given the info I have.  The error seems to indicate that an invalid column but from what you've given I can't add anything more to assist.  Sorry about that and best of luck to you in figuring it out.  I would strip everything down to the barest minimum on your Code first side and in your controller action to get it to work and then work your way back up.  It sounds like you have already started to do that.  You'll find the culprit soon enough. :-)